# Is there a Evernote client?

Tags: software-recommendation, evernote

**Evernote** is a cool site for capturing note, tagging it and retrieving it from everywhere. The Web application is nice but I was wondering if anyone knows about a standalone version such as for Windows, Android,... but for Ubuntu ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe they don't have Linux support but here is a cool article on various [alternatives](https://web.archive.org/web/20101201132531/www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/322137-finding-evernote-replacements-for-linux).

Comment: Odd that this is the accepted answer as all it details is how to avoid using Evernote.  I use Nevernote myself and it's flawless - in many ways far superior to the actual Windows client of Evernote itself.  Horses for courses, I suppose.  Evernote is cross-client and supports Android, which for me is essential.

Answer (score 10):

Not an official one, but I've had success with the unofficial client [NeverNote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 Thanks, didn't know about this. Works nicely on 10.04

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, you can use [NixNote (previously Nevernote)](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/evernote-for-linux-nevernote.html), an unofficial Evernote client written in Java but if you want something lightweight, you should try [Everpad](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad), a new Evernote client that integrates nicely with Unity.

It supports online sync, notes, tags, notebooks, file attachments (remember there's a 60 MB monthly limit) and places.

[image]

[image]

### Installation:

To install Everpad all you need to do is run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install everpad
```

Once installed all you need to do is search for ‘Everpad’ in the Unity Dash and then run the Everpad application. You will then see the app indicator appear on your panel. Once it does, click on it and select “Settings & Management” then “Authorise” to configure Everpad with your Evernote account.

To create a new note, simply click on the Everpad app indicator and select “Create Note” or click on an existing note to edit it.

[image]

### Troubleshooting:

Having a issue? Report them [@Github](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues?state=open)

---

Sources: [Omg Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/use-evernote-in-ubuntu-with-everpad)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a native client :-(

So, your best bet might be to run it in wine. e.g.: http://abbysays.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/how-to-install-evernote-30-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

Not really, no. You might consider running the web app in [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/), which is quite a nice bit of kit that allows you to run a web app in a standalone window/browser. Or you can use Wine, which works fairly well with Evernote.

Answer (score 2):

As of March 2021 there **WAS** a **beta** version of an **official Evernote client** for Linux (a deb package) available. If you agreed to provide Evernote with feedback via a single email survey, you could download it from the [Early Access Evernote homepage](https://evernote.com/intl/en/b1433t1422) as deb-package. The deb-package can be installed with the Software Center, other tools or [via the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) as usual.
**More infos** you can find on [It is FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/install-evernote-ubuntu/.).
**But very soon this page was deleted.**
Hopefully there will be soon an official version without the beta-status.

Maybe you can still get this beta version through the [**Early Access program**](https://evernote.com/earlyaccess/), see [a blog article about this](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025162234-Join-the-Evernote-Early-Access-Program).

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Tomboy/Dropbox.

Add Gnome-do and it's extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed Evernote app for Android as Chrome's extension on Ubuntu using [this tutorial](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/install-android-apps-ubuntu-archon). It looks like separate app: can be found in Ubuntu's search and can be locked to sidebar. For now it seems to be working: I've signed into account, synchronized, can see notes, tags and other things, that I can see on my Android tablet. Also I've tried to create note, add tag to it and sync. Found this note on tablet. Nice!

I can't say, that functionality of this client is enough for me, because I did not test it for a long time, but it's very good alternative for native linux Evernote not official clients.

Comment: Also I've tried to add attachments to notes, that calls standard Ubuntu's open file dialog and it works well. And downloaded attachments from notes: attachments are saving in special folder, that emulates Android home folder exclusively for Evernote in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of **Dropbox** for folder sync in multiple computers, and **Tomboy** for note-taking.

Setup **Dropbox** first, then setup **Tomboy**'s folder within Dropbox's folder.
Do this in every computer you use.

Also, both can be used in multiple platforms.

Comment: Ubuntu One syncs Tomboy notes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[Tomboy and UbuntuOne](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Notes) has worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [emacs-evernote-mode](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-evernote-mode/), that let's you edit and create notes in Emacs using either XHTML or TEXT mode. The cool part is that you can post a region from any Buffer as a note with a single command `M-x evernote-post-region`. I realize this is probably appealing only for Emacs users (such as myself).

Answer (score 0):

There's a new client called ForeverNote

https://github.com/milan102/ForeverNote

Answer (score 0):

As the [official beta deb-package is not available anymore](https://askubuntu.com/a/1320825/30631), alternatives are welcome:

1. [**Tusk** - Refined Evernote desktop app](https://klaussinani.github.io/tusk/), there are several possibilities how to install it, see the [release page on Github](https://github.com/klaussinani/tusk/releases/latest).
2. [**Nixnote2** - A clone of Evernote for Linux](https://github.com/baumgarr/nixnote2), available from the official repositories or a PPA.
3. **[Running Evernote in Firefox](https://itsfoss.com/install-evernote-ubuntu/#comments/349585)**: Since its latest updates (2021) it runs very smoothly, it’s pretty quick and can be closed simply by closing the tab