# How do I install a .deb file via the command line?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

How do I install a `.deb` file via the command line?

Comment: Find better: http://www.steptoinstall.com/step-to-install-deb-file-using-command-line-terminal-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Complete answer : [How to install a deb file, by dpkg -i or by apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159094/86583)

Comment: Related: [How to let `dpkg -i` install dependencies for me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me)

Comment: I use gdebi `sudo gdebi ./app.deb`

Answer (score 1607, accepted):

Packages are **manually** installed via the **`dpkg`** command (Debian Package Management System). `dpkg` is the backend to commands like `apt-get` and `aptitude`, which in turn are the backend for GUI install apps like the Software Center and Synaptic.

Something along the lines of:

`dpkg` --> `apt-get`, `aptitude` --> Synaptic, Software Center

But of course the easiest ways to install a package would be, first, the GUI apps (Synaptic, Software Center, etc..), followed by the terminal commands `apt-get` and `aptitude` that add a very nice user friendly approach to the backend dpkg, including but not limited to packaged dependencies, control over what is installed, needs update, not installed, broken packages, etc.. Lastly the `dpkg` command which is the base for all of them.

Since dpkg is the base, you can use it to install packaged directly from the command line.

#### Install a package

```
sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE
```

For example if the package file is called `askubuntu_2.0.deb` then you should do `sudo dpkg -i askubuntu_2.0.deb`. If `dpkg` reports an error due to dependency problems, you can run `sudo apt-get install -f` to download the missing dependencies and configure everything. If that reports an error, you'll have to sort out the dependencies yourself by following for example [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies).

#### Remove a package

```
sudo dpkg -r PACKAGE_NAME
```

For example if the package is called `askubuntu` then you should do `sudo dpkg -r askubuntu`.

#### Reconfigure an existing package

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure PACKAGE_NAME
```

This is useful when you need to reconfigure something related to said package. Some useful examples it the `keyboard-configuration` when you want to enable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in order to reset the X server, so you would the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Another great one is when you need to set the Timezone for a server or your local testing computer, so you use use the `tzdata` package:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: Great info, had to find some way to install traceroute to help debug why my machine won't connect to the internet :)

Comment: Also helpful to note that once installed programs are usually found in /usr/bin, named after what was depackaged.

Comment: If I run `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`, it has failed for months with "Hash Sum mismatch". I can download the .deb file from `http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-base/texlive-latex-base-doc_2015.20150625-1ubuntu1_all.deb`. If I install it using dpkg, would it subsequently be recognised (and updated) by apt-get.

Comment: Hi @user643722 I was going to recommend deleting the cached version of that package but here you have an answer for the issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: If it's easier and better to install via `aptitude` or `apt-get` (or simply `apt`), why aren't examples for these commands given here?

Comment: The question is about deb files not packages. I do understand the idea of showing everything in a single answer (am with you in this one) but the OP would need to rephrase the question. Good point btw.

Comment: [To get binaries associated with the package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394605/209677) usually works just: `dpkg -L PACKAGE_NAME | egrep '/bin/|/sbin/'`, or just with `grep bin/`usually also works.

Comment: With modern `apt` I would recommend doing `sudo apt install ./package.deb` instead. This allows automatically installing all the dependencies and it does all the extra sanity checks that `dpkg` will not implement because it's a low level command. Note that without the prefix `/` or `./` some versions of `apt` may not understand that you're trying to refer to file name, not a package name from repository.

Answer (score 202):

Debian (.deb) packages are the packages that are used in Ubuntu. You can install any .deb package in your system. .deb files can generally be installed from your file manager (Nautilus) merely by clicking on them, since file associations with the default installer is already set in Ubuntu. These instructions are for those who wish to install packages from the command-line terminal (Terminal).

To install a downloaded Debian (Ubuntu) package (.deb): Open Terminal and type

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

To remove a Debian (Ubuntu) package (.deb):

```
sudo dpkg -r packagename
```

To Reconfigure/Repair an installed Debian (Ubuntu) package (.deb):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure packagename
```

Comment: clicking on them doesn't work as of Ubuntu 22, it opens them as an archive

Answer (score 124):

My favourite is GDebi, available from both terminal/shell or graphical desktop.

[image: screen-shot]

I usually associate `.deb` files with GDebi as it is fast and efficient - especially compared to Ubuntu Software Center. **One of the main feature of GDebi is it resolves dependencies and installs them.**

For command-line run `sudo gdebi <package.deb>` to install a single deb file.

Comment: it checks for dependencies before installing, thx!!

Comment: Can gdebi even download the dependencies or we have to download them manually?? @Pandya

Comment: Probably better for people moving in from the non-Linux background.

Comment: +1 for "it resolves dependencies and installs them" which is key.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Using `dpkg -i` requires deeper understanding of how the package system works. GDebi does things automatically.

Additionally, for those who want a non-gui solution, gdebi has a -n, --non-interactive option. It's like dpkg but it checks for dependencies first and refuses to install if dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: Great answer for a guy coming from MS world

Answer (score 104):

While `dpkg -i` indeed installs the package, it doesn't do any automatic dependency resolution. Meanwhile there are two other alternatives, using `gdebi` or the `apt-get` tool. To use the latter just use:

```
sudo apt-get install /path/to/package.deb
```

Even if you are on the directory with the package, you need to give a path using `./` at the start:

```
sudo apt-get install ./package.deb
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. `apt` will prevent you from breaking your​ system if you don't have the correct dependencies.

Comment: This command seems to select all existing packages.

Comment: @Hibou57 there can't be any space in the package name.

Comment: I have an understanding `apt-get` will download and install latest deb from repos, to prevent that turn network off before install. Even cleaner install is by copying file (or several deb files together) to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and running `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`, that way as I've noticed `apt` is not trying to download from internet.

Answer (score 96):

Are you looking for all **dpkg** commands? click this link to have a read.

[15 dpkg commands to Manage Debian based Linux Servers](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/30-dpkg-commands-to-manage-debian-based-linux-servers/)

## DPKG commands

There are two actions, they are `dpkg-query` and `dpkg-deb`.

#### Install a package

```
# sudo dpkg -i {package_name}    
# sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

#### Remove a package

```
# sudo dpkg -r {package_name}
# sudo dpkg -r vlc
```

#### Remove a package and its configuration files

```
# sudo dpkg -P {package_name}
# sudo dpkg -P vlc
```

#### List all installed packages.

You can pipe the command to `less` (a pager) so you can more easily scroll the content:

```
# dpkg -l | less
```

#### Check if the package is installed or not

```
# dpkg -l {package_name}
# dpkg -l vlc
```

#### Check if the package is installed or not, and if it is, launch it:

```
# dpkg -l | vlc
```

#### See whether a package is installed or not

And this will show the location where the package will be installed.
Here `-S` (capital `S`) to search whether the package was installed or not.

```
# sudo dpkg -S {package_name}
# sudo dpkg -S skype
```

#### Install a *.deb package from a specified location

Here `-R` is recursive. (Recursively handle all regular files matching the pattern  `*.deb` found at specified directories and all of its subdirectories).

```
# sudo dpkg -R --install {package_location}
# sudo dpkg -R --install /home/sysadmin/soft
```

#### Show package details

Here `-p` (lowercase `p`) will show the package info:

```
# dpkg -p {package_name}
# dpkg -p apache2
```

#### View the content of a package

Use `-c` (lowercase `c`) to show the content:

```
# sudo dpkg -c {package_name}
# sudo dpkg -c skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

#### Extract the `*.deb` package file

Use `-x` (lowercase `x`) to extract:

```
# dpkg -x {package_name} {location_were_to_extract}
# dpkg -x libqt4-phonon_4.6.3-4+squeeze1_i386.deb /home/sysadmin/
```

#### Extract and display the filenames contained in a package

Use `-X` (uppercase `X`) to display the content with extraction.

```
# dpkg -X {package_name} {location_were_to_extract}
# dpkg -X libqt4-phonon_4.6.3-4+squeeze1_i386.deb /home/sysadmin/
```

#### Display information about a package

Here `-I` stands for information:

```
# dpkg -I {package_name}
# dpkg -I libqt4-phonon_4.6.3-4+squeeze1_i386.deb
```

#### Reconfigure an already installed package

`dpkg-reconfigure` reconfigures packages after they already have been installed. Pass it the name(s) of a package or packages to reconfigure. It will ask configuration questions, much like when the package was first installed.

```
# dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

This will reconfigure `postfix` the same way as when you installed it for the first time.

Need to know more about `dpkg` commands? Have a look at the manual page:

```
# man dpkg
```

Comment: "*Check if the package is installed or not, and if it is, launch it: `# dpkg -l | vlc`*" - this would only pipe a list of packages to vlc, with unpredictable results if it were installed; and no better than just typing `vlc`

Answer (score 29):

A handy tip when installing a program like Libreoffice which has multiple .deb files in a folder is to use.

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: Never use this command. You have to manually remove all debs if want to remove that package. `sudo apt remove example` ,`sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo dpkg -r *.deb` doesn't work.

Answer (score 21):

I have literally been waiting for this for *years*:

```
sudo apt install ./happy-at-long-last.deb
```

Yay! :)  This works from [APT 1.1](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/apt-1-1-released/) which should be available on most systems by now.

Using `dpkg` has regularly caused problems for me, whereas `apt` is very good at automatically resolving dependencies and avoiding problems.  And it's still low-level enough to allow scripting and fine-tuning...

Comment: This is now the "right" answer and should really be first in the list. I don't think SO/AskUbuntu lets moderators manually change the order of listed answers though. It was a long time coming!

Answer (score 18):

Installing `.deb` files can be accomplished using:

```bash
sudo apt install ./<file>.deb
```

If you're on an older distribution, you will need to run this instead:

```bash
sudo dpkg -i ./<file>.deb
sudo apt-get install -f        # Installing missing dependencies
```

---

Another approach is by using the [gdebi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gdebi.1.html) tool to install deb files.

Answer (score 17):

## The `gdebi` command-line solution

Here's the best way to install a .deb file on Ubuntu on the command-line:

```
sudo gdebi skype.deb
```

If you don't have `gdebi` installed already, install it using `sudo apt install gdebi-core`.

## Why gdebi?

`gdebi` will look for all the dependencies of the `.deb` file, and will install them before attempting to install the `.deb` file. I find this much preferable than `sudo dpkg -i skype.deb && sudo apt install -f`. The latter is much too eager to remove dependencies in certain situations. For instance, when I tried to install Skype, it attempted to remove 96 (!) packages, including packages like `compiz` and `unity`! `gdebi` gave a much clearer error message:

```
$ sudo gdebi skype.deb
Cannot install 'libqtgui:i386'
```

(Here is [the solution to that particular issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/553283/2355), by the way.)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/170557/158442 does say `gdebi` can be used from the command line

Comment: @muru Yeah, but it's easy to miss because of the screenshot. Also, it doesn't explain the problems with `dpkg -i skype.deb`

Answer (score 13):

Create your own script installer `debInstaller` as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg -i "$@"
apt-get --yes --fix-broken install
```

Make the script executable with

```
chmod +x debInstaller
```

Then move it to some dirs in your PATH or add the current directory to your PATH.

I'm going to move it to /usr/bin

```
sudo cp debInstaller /usr/bin
```

Now you can install any `.deb` package using the command:

```
sudo debInstaller some-package.deb
```

The added value of this method is the solving the dependencies problem, since mostly you'll face some problems when you install a `.deb`  with `dpkg -i` due to dependencies error, so you have to use `apt-get install -f` to solve it, this script will do the job for you, but here I used `apt-get --yes --fix-broken install` to automatically solve these errors without user intervention.

Answer (score 6):

There are many tools to install a deb package.

I personally use a built-in package installer **[dpkg](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html)**:

1. If you are **logged as root**:

- Change the directory to location of deb package

  ```
  dpkg -i package_name.deb
  ```

2. If you are **not logged as a root**:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
   ```

To make sure that package was installed correctly and **didn't have any broken dependencies**:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

If there are any **broken dependencies**:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 3):

If file is only one, then afaik `dpkg -i /path/file.deb` is ok and simple (make sure apt user has access to the path, for user home folder it usually does not).

In case of several deb files (e.g. one package) sometimes `dpkg` tries to process them in order where dependencies are not satisfied along the way. In such case clean and simplest way is by copying several deb files together to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and running `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`, that way as I've noticed `apt` is not trying to download from internet repos as it does if `apt-get install /some_other_path/*.deb`.

*Added to possibly make more future proof / general:*

`apt` cache location theoretically might be not in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, to get the location:

```
eval $(apt-config shell CACHE Dir::Cache)
eval $(apt-config shell ARCHIVES Dir::Cache::archives)
debs_cache_folder=/${CACHE}/${ARCHIVES}
```